# With std::istream::operator>> working on unsigned types, how do I tell apart a failed extraction from an underflow?

Tags: c++, io, iostream

I want to use std::istream::operator>> to extract data into unsigned types (that's inside a template so it can be ushort, uint, etc). Specifically, I'm using std::stringstream to parse std::string lines extracted from a file with std::getline() calls.

Since I'm reading from a file, those extractions can fail for different reasons: underflow, overflow and "bad extraction". Such cases are handled by the STL:

> If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set. If extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in value, std::numeric_limits::max() or std::numeric_limits::min() is written and failbit flag is set.

[source: cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)

Problem: std::numeric_limits::min() equals 0 for unsigned types, so there's no way to know if I'm reading something that isn't an integer (in which case I'm aborting the program) or if it's just an underflow (in which case I'm just clamping the value and emitting a warning).

How do I solve this without using bigger and/or signed equivalents of the unsigned type I'm working with?

Comment: I bet your problem is something different actually: How to serialize/deserialze user defined data. Am I right?

Comment: I think the sad answer is that `std::istream::operator>>` just don't offer the error message granularity that you want. I can see two ways you can go: **1)** Read into a signed long (or some other bigger datatype), use the extra space to check if clamping is needed, and then just treat all extraction errors as "bad input: abort". **2)** Write your own "read value from a character-stream" function, with as finely granular error reporting as you need/want.

Comment: @nada It's a deserializer, yes. I was testing fringe cases (user feeding an int file to an unsigned int deserializer, which should only raise underflow warnings) and noticed this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsigned type won't underflow. If you mean "underflow" by inputting a negative number, the standard stream does not treat it as an error. The negative number is wrapped around into the unsigned type, and `failbit` is NOT set.

Hence, if you see 0 stored and `failbit` is set, you can assert it is an extraction failure. To detect negative number error, you have to do some extra work. For example, you can first read the value in an (large enough) signed integer type to detect if it is negative.

Comment: Indeed, I did some research and it seems std::strtoull() works as you describe. Quote: "If the minus sign was part of the input sequence, the numeric value calculated from the sequence of digits is negated as if by unary minus in the result type, which applies unsigned integer wraparound rules". Since istream::operator>> is (indirectly) based on it, it's reasonable to think it works the same way.